# Dspace Rest API response: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below"

Tags: rest, api, dspace

I'm using dspace6 and I installed REST API.

When I type `http://path-to-server:8080/rest/test` I see the REST API is running.

When I request `http://path-to-server:8080/rest/communities` I get this response:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information
>   associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: That's not an error as such, your browser is simply saying it's going to display the plain XML response with no formatting information, because there isn't any available. Perfectly normal for an API to return non-formatted XML, since generally the purpose is data exchange between two applications, and not display to humans. What is your concern in this situation, exactly? You haven't actually asked us a question.

Comment: sorry iam newer .
tell what should i do to return gui responce for user
 iam using google chrome

Comment: An API isn't intending for giving a response directly to your user. If you want to display that info to the user in a user-friendly way then build a GUI application (using HTML if you like) which makes a HTTP request (e.g. via Javascript/AJAX) to the API to get the data, and then write some code which presents that data nicely in a way a human would like to see it. The API is meant for sending info machine-to-machine (e.g. from one program to another), not for direct use by humans.